# How to fix laravel eloquent many to many relation insertion error on wrong table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a model class with the name `CourseSession` and it's table is `course_session`, and I have another model named `Student` and it's table is `student` and every session has many students and also every student could be in many sessions. So I have created a third table named `student_session` with `student_id`, `session_id`, `presence` and laravels timestamp columns.

Creating a session needs to have a list of students and I get them from `$request` like this:

```php
$validatedData = $request->validate([
    'students' => 'required',
]);
```

`students` is array of students id!

this is my `CourseSession` model:

```php
class CourseSession extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'course_sessions';
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function course()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Course');
    }

    public function students()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Student', 'student_session','session_id', 'student_id');
    }
}
```

and this is my student model:

```php
class Student extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function courses()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Course');
    }

    public function exams()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Exam');
    }

    public function sessions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\CourseSession', 'student_session', 'student_id', 'session_id');
    }
}
```

I create a session like this:

```php
$session = new CourseSession();
$session->course_id = $course->id;
$session->save();
```

and I save students this way:

```php
$sessions = $session->students()->create(['session_id' => $session->id, 'student_id' => 1, 'presence' => 1]);
```

but I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'session_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `students` (`session_id`, `student_id`, `presence`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (25, 1, 1, 2019-04-28 14:24:48, 2019-04-28 14:24:48))
```

according to error, it tries to write data on `students` table but I want to write them on `student_session` table!

what is wrong in my codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you want to use [attach()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) instead of `create()`.

```
$session->students()->attach(1, ['presence' => 1]);
```

In the above example `1` is the `student_id`. You don't need to specify the `session_id` as your calling this from a `Session` model. The array at the end is any additional data you want to add to the pivot table.

Since you have additional data in your `student_session` pivot table, it might also be an idea to add this to your `belongsToMany` relationships e.g.

```
public function sessions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\CourseSession', 'student_session', 'student_id', 'session_id')
        ->withPivot('presence')
        ->withTimestamps();
}
```

This will include the `presence` and timestamps columns in the pivot data as well (obviously, you don't have to do this if you don't want to though).

Comment: I changed my code but now I receive this error: " SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'session_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `student_session` (`created_at`, `presence`, `session_id`, `student_id`, `updated_at`) values (2019-04-28 19:52:30, 1, 33, 1, 2019-04-28 19:52:30)) "

Comment: @AmirSasani Does you `student_session` table not have a `session_id` column??

Comment: it was my mistake and sent a wrong data to it, thank you